# Load HTML file into VBA Microsoft Access Email

Tags: html, ms-access, outlook, vba

I am trying to load an HTML file into an email that gets sent by my Microsoft Access database. The email gets sent when the user clicks a button (Command109)
Here is my code that sends the email:

```
Private Sub Command109_Click()
'Start of code
Dim strEmail, strBody As String
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem

'Creates an instance of Outlook
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

DoEvents

Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

DoEvents

'Creates string with email address
strEmail = PayeeEmail
strBody = "WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE TO LOAD AN EXTERNAL HTML FILE?"

DoEvents

'Creates and sends email
With objEmail

DoEvents
.To = strEmail

DoEvents
.Subject = "Your Distribution from " & COMPANY & " has been processed."

DoEvents
.HTMLBody = strBody
DoEvents
DoEvents
.Send
End With

Set objEmail = Nothing
'Closes Outlook. Remove if you do not want to close Outlook
'objOutlook.Quit
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I have this other code that allows me to load an HTML file into Outlook, but I'm not sure how to combine the code - so that the HTML file gets loaded into the BODY of the email being sent by Access.

Here is the code I have for a macro that will load an HTML file into Outlook:

```
Sub insertHTML()
Dim insp As Inspector
Set insp = ActiveInspector
If insp.IsWordMail Then
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = insp.WordEditor
wordDoc.Application.Selection.InsertFile "C:\Users\me\Desktop\emailtemplate.html",
, False, False, False
End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me figure this out? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate strings on multiple lines you must have a space between the '&' and '_' as they are separate operators.

```
strBody = "<html><p> some of my html text here" & _  'Note the spaces
          "more formatted html text here" & _
          "even more formatted html text here" & _
          "don't forget your closing html brackets</p></html>"

with objEmail
    .to = strTo
    .subject = strSubject
    .HTMKBody = strBody
    .send
end with
```

For ease of readability in the code you can even create a seperate module with just the email string, just make sure it's public so that it can be called.

```
public strBody as string = your string here
```

Comment: Thank you again for your time! Adding the space did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about importing an HTML file directly, however in the past I have just placed the HTML code straight into the module.  This is possible because you're using the .HTMLBody instead of .Body. You can also insert variable into the HTML code this way.

Straight HTML string

```
strBody = "<html> YOUR HTML CODE HERE </html>"
```

HTML using VBA variables

```
strBody = "<html><p> This is an email from " & COMPANY & ". We value your business</p></html>"
```

Obviously this isn't ideal if the template will change frequently.  When I've done this in the past I've just made a template in outlook, copied the HTML code into VBA and then inserted variables where I wanted them.

There is likely a better way to do this though.

Comment: Yea, I see I can do that - but I'm limited to a certain amount of characters within the VBA string. So I end up not having enough space to fit all my HTML and CSS stylings - hence wanting to load a separate HTML file into the body. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: There is no character limit for strings in vba. The size limit is about 2gb.

Comment: There is a line limit however. This can be solved using & _ to continue the string on a new line.

Comment: There must always be a space after the &